# Script to determine if a TAP interface created by a service is up

Tags: centos, tap

My system has a SoftEther VPN service that creates it's own TAP interface when it starts and removes it when it's stops. But even with DHCP running on the VPN, the TAP doesn't configure it's own IP when it comes up or the static IP configured in `ifcfg` file specific to it. However, it does configure it's DHCP IP if I do `dhclient` or run `ifup` (with `ifcfg` present).

My question is, how do I script monitoring if the interface is up and run either `dhclient` or `ifup`, whichever I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I did on a Centos7, I did resolve it with sysmtemd-networkd. It listenings on all network devices you specify on /etc/systemd/network/

For example, 20-static-tap_clients.network looks like:

```
[Match]
Name=tap_clients
[Network]
Address=192.168.103.1/24
```

Changing `tap_clients` with your tap interface name and modifying de IP address for the IP you want.

You must disable NetworkManager service and enable systemd-networkd.
As for softether, I did also create the unit files and placed them on /usr/lib/systemd/system

softether-vpnserver.service

```
[Unit]
Description=SoftEther VPN Server
After=network.target auditd.service
ConditionPathExists=!/opt/vpnserver/do_not_run

[Service]
Type=forking
EnvironmentFile=-/opt/vpnserver
ExecStart=/opt/vpnserver/vpnserver start
ExecStop=/opt/vpnserver/vpnserver stop
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=softether-vpnserver.service
```

softether-vpnbridge.service

```
[Unit]
Description=SoftEther VPN Bridge
After=network.target auditd.service
ConditionPathExists=!/opt/vpnbridge/do_not_run

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/opt/vpnbridge/vpnbridge start
ExecStop=/opt/vpnbridge/vpnbridge stop
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=softether-vpnserver.service
```

and softether-vpnclient.service

```
[Unit]
Description=SoftEther VPN Client
After=network.target auditd.service
ConditionPathExists=!/opt/vpnclient/do_not_run

[Service]
Type=forking
EnvironmentFile=-/opt/vpnclient
ExecStart=/opt/vpnclient/vpnclient start
ExecStop=/opt/vpnclient/vpnclient stop
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=softether-vpnclient.service
```

Comment: Great answer, a shame the CentOS system in question only has Upstart.

Answer (score 0):

You could do watch for interface in a while loop like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
trap exit 1 2 15
while true; do
    if [ "$(ip l | fgrep IFACE: | wc -l)" -gt 0 ]; then
        # run dhclient/ifup for your IFACE here
        break
    fi
    sleep 1
done
```

But I hope SoftEther VPN can configure TAP interface, there must be an option for script that user writes or options that control TAP interface configuration somewhere, in configuration file(s) or gui of the program.

Comment: SoftEther configuring it's own interface is indeed for the best. AFAIK however, there are no options in the configuration files. Maybe I haven't read the docs closely enough. **:/**